# Lightroom to Photoshop to Pixiset

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

There must be a more efficient process than what I am doing. I import all my RAW images to Lightroom.  I then open them in Photoshop to make some additional tweaks.  From here I save them as JPEGS. Then I upload the JPEGS to my Pixiset account.  It is such a process!! Even when I am not opening to Photoshop I still have to save all the files as JPEG's before uploading them to Pixiset. Is there a way to take my RAW images in Lightroom and send them directly to my Pixiset account?

Similarly when someone creates a favorites list in Pixiset there seems to be a way to copy the files they selected and search for only these file names in Lightroom, but it doesn't seem to work for me. Lightroom can't seem to find any of my file names, ever. Any tips?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You can download [official plugin](https://pixieset.com/tools/) from Pixiset for Lightroom. This will help you to drag and drop images in plugin (in Lightroom) and publish them directly in Pixiset. Background export to JPG is inevitable, but those temporary files are destroyed after the publish process is finished.